# How to edit in Permalinks Custom Structure example.edu.mm/%category%/%postname%/ not working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

example.edu.mm/category
above the link is working on my hosting but
the following link is not working on my hosting
example.com.mm/category/postname/
my Custom Structure of permalinks is example.edu.mm/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: http://example.edu.mm/category

above the link is working on my hosting but
the following link is not working on my hosting

http://example.edu.mm/category/postname/

my Custom Structure of permalinks is http://example.edu.mm/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Your question just isn't appropriate please change your question title.